# Is Sigma 50-500mm EX DG HSM lens compatible with a Nikon D90 body?

Tags: lens, autofocus, nikon-d90, sigma, compatibility

Aloha,

Can anyone tell me if the Sigma 50-500mm EX DG HSM lens (non OS model) is compatible with a Nikon D90 body?  I recently purchased this lens on eBay but it seems that the lens will not autofocus on my D90.  Is this lens only compatible with full-frame DSLRs?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you got sold a lemon. It should work just fine, if it won't focus either the motors are broken and/or the other electronics are causing trouble with the camera's autofocus system.

Answer (score 1):

If your camera / lens is not broken, it probably just needs a firmware update for the Sigma. That was a commonly enough reported issue with the original 50-500mm when used with "newer" cameras.